# Getting 404 error on category page

Tags: collection, category, ce-1.8.1.0

I have 2 root categories and subcategories in every one of them.

One of root category(Default Category) and sub categories are showing on navigation menu. It's OK. That's what I want.

The other root category (name: Collections) is not showing in navigation menu and I can't access any collections's subcategory's page. It's getting 404 error.

I think it's related to **`System > Manage Stores`** page root category settings. It's saying Root category is default category.

So If you understand what I mean, how can I access not-default root category(Collections)'s subcategories?

Comment: One website allowed to have one root category.

Comment: I have Installed the latest Magento 2.3 And having Multilingual Store. I mentioned the default root category as in Store. But when coming to Front End you can see the categories but when to click to open them it shows 404 Error not Found.
Can anyone please help me to solve this. I added few products to those categories to check but cannot redirect to the categories page which shows an error. Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

In Magento you can only have one root category per store.

If you are unfamiliar with Magento's Global->Website->Store->Storeview Scope structure , try reading something like 
this: [Magento Multi Store, Websites and Storeviews Explained](http://edmondscommerce.github.io/magento/magento-multi-store-websites-and-storeviews-explained.html)  
or this:[How to set multiple websites with multiple store views in Magento](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-set-multiple-websites-with-multiple-store-views-in-magento/)

Long story short. In the front-end you cannot have two Root Categories shown simultaneously. Make two Level-1 categories Root->Default and Root->Collections and move the respective subcategories in there.